# Error in Toad - ora 12154

Tags: oracle, toad

I am trying to make a connection using Toad to a database (xe10 free edition) and it givea me a error:

ORA-12154

I tried changing the sqlnetORA to:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)
```

and still the same error.

Comment: try to `ping` to the database server

Comment: i find that IP is: 198.11.34.43
is correct? i attach the ping
Estadísticas de ping para 198.11.34.43:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),

Comment: sorry I think that is not English

Comment: is not a database., is my personal laptop windows 7 64 bits

Comment: Did you check the tnsnames.ora file ? can you provide its contents ?

Comment: ORA-12154 indicates that the database identifier you supplied isn't defines in your TNSNAMES.ORA file. Check your TNSNAMES.ORA.

Comment: first of all., happy new year!! and thank you for your time., well honostlly i am obsessed and soon i am gone be crazy, because i am stuck with this absurd thing., i need to make a lot of query's in Toad based in various large flat files imported., but is imposible to make the conection in my new laptop windows 7!! (i hate it) 100 time better xp

Comment: tnsnames: XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vili-pc)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )

Comment: sqlnet: SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

Comment: listener:SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vili-pc)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

Comment: OK guys at leat i fixet., well the whole thing is that in the new laptops with windows 7 when you download toad is go to program files (x86) and for that reason is not working., so i copied from x86 and paste in to another folder program files and BINGO! :D., hope that someday this help somebody after i spend yesterday so many hours front of pc

Answer (score 1):

1st check to make sure you can ping the database, if yes move to next step if not resolve firewall/network issues.

2nd check to see if you can connect via SQL*plus. If you can connect with SQL+ then your TNS is fine and Toad seems to be the issue, if you cannot then there is an issue with your TNS file.

Be sure to try and connect directly using the following method:

```
In Toad click "Session" > "New Connection"
There are 3 options TNS, Direct, LDAP (Shown as Tabs) . Select "Direct"
User: sys
Password : <passwd>
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 1521
Service Name: XE
Connect as: SYSDBA
```

If you are unable to connect via SQL+ or Toad then fix your .tns, I have attached a few helpful links below which should help resolve your problem.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12154_tns_resolve_service_name.htm 
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 0):

try to comment the following line in sqlnet.ora

```
#names.default_domain = world
```

otherwise, Oracle will append .world to your host string

Answer (score -1):

Often, it's a typographical error in your connexion string or in your tnsnames.ora file. More information here : [11g/ORA-12154](http://www.oracle-error.com/11g/ORA-12154.html).